# dereferencing pointer to array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to understand how a pointer to an array of pointers works.

I have the following struct

```
typedef struct Array {
    int capacity;
    int size;
    void **items;
} Array;
```

and the following function which allocates memory for the struct and returns a pointer to it

```
Array *createArray(int capacity) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array *));
    array->capacity = capacity;
    array->size = 0;
    void **items = malloc(sizeof(void *) * array->capacity *  sizeof *items);
    if(items == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    array->items = items;
    return array;
}
```

Now, I want to initialize an array of pointers to this struct. Here's how I am doing that

```
Array *(*createHashTable(int size))[10] {
    Array *array[10]; 
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = createArray(size);
    }
    Array *(*ptr)[10] = &array;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", (*(ptr[0] + i))->capacity);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

The print statement gives me what I expect: which is

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Now, my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Array *(*ptr)[10] = createHashTable(10);
    printf("%d\n", (*(ptr[0]+9))->capacity);
    return 0;
}
```

So far, everything makes sense to me, with the printf statement in `main` working fine. However, the part that confuses me is if I place a for loop inside my `main` function like so

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Array *(*ptr)[10] = createHashTable(10);
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", (*(ptr[0] + i))->capacity);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output,

```
10
10
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why is my program seg faulting only when I loop? Am I missing something basic about returning a pointer to an array of pointers?

Comment: `Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array *));`->`Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array));`

Comment: I am a little surprised, because there is one case where you used the never wrong `sizeof(*VARIABLE)`. For instance `Array *array = malloc(sizeof(*array))` would never be wrong. Even if you change `Array *array;` to `Array ****array;`! Oh, and that's an interesting return type for a function, not to mention that it makes [tag:c] a weird language.

Comment: @coderredoc - Hey, do you mind elaborating on why that will fix it? I'm not following...

Comment: @random_coder_101 It's not a pointer that you're allocating, it's an instance of the structure. `sizeof(Array *)` is equal to the size of any pointer, even `sizeof(void *)`, so it's allocating either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the platform and OS. But you really, need `sizeof(Array)` bytes to allocate.

Answer (score 2):

**First**. The problem appears to be that you are not allocating enough memory,

```
Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array *));
```

allocates only `sizeof(void *)` bytes, and that's probably less than `sizeof(Array)`<sup>1</sup>

So when you try to initialize the returned `array` you are accessing memory that you did not allocate, thus invoking undefined behavior.

To be always right on the ammount of memory, use the following syntax

```
Array *array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
```

this way you ensure that you are allocating the correct size.

**Second**. If you see that the values were printed as expected, blame it on *undefined behavior*. Because your code has invoked it, it will not go away after you did, and the problem will appear sooner, later or perhaps never, but it's still there. That's the worst thing about undefined behavior, since it's undefined you cannot predict when or whether it will happen.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>In fact it's surely less, because you need at least `sizeof(void *) + 2 * sizeof(int)`, that is if you ignore padding.</sub>

Comment: It's also probably better to do a one-shot allocation of M*N entries and then split out those chunks into separate pointers, giving you a contiguous region of memory. Separate allocations may lead to fragmentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have made any difference. My code is still segfaulting in the exact same way.
Also, this still doesn't explain why the loop in createHashTable printed out the values correctly, right?

Comment: @random_coder_101, what OS are you working with? and remove that horrible return type, use a `typedef` or something! It's just a suggestion.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi - macOS High Sierra v0.13.1

Answer (score 1):

```
Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array *));
```

should be

```
Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array));
```

`sizeof(Array *)` is just size of a pointer, while `sizeof(Array)` is size of the structure `Array`.

But I don't know exactly what happened in your code, as it went wrong at `array->items = items;` in my computer, maybe you can try `printf("%d\n", &((*(ptr[0]+9))->capacity));` to get the address and work out what exactly is in this address with `gdb`.

Comment: What do you mean "*it went wrong ... in my computer*"? Are you aware of undefined behavior?

Comment: What I mean is it is undefined behavior, so the result by my compiler is different from @random_coder_101.